# Generating symfony2 form on Bootstrap popover is slow

Tags: php, jquery, forms, twitter-bootstrap, symfony

Generating forms using Symfony2 is nice when you go from one page to another, but when you want a form to be generated on the fly and attached to a bootstrap popover, it really slows down the popover from showing (or the form itself) because of the AJAX request/response (which gives back the symfony2 form html).

I have a calendar, much like Google Calendar and I want a form to be generated for each slot clicked on it. Google Calendar is really nice and smooth, and opens the popover alongside a text field instantly, no lags. How can I achieve that smoothness and still keep using Symfony2 forms?

Right now I've disregarded Symfony2 forms to handle the issue but I don't like doing it this way. I've attached this html form directly and I'm handling the processing using the Request object parameters in Symfony2 conroller:

```
<form class="form-horizontal picker-popover" role="form" data-form="schedule-picker">
<div class="col-sm-6">
<select class="form-control" data-type="start-time" name="startTime">
<option selected value="0">START TIME</option>
</select>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6">
<select class="form-control" data-type="end-time" name="endTime">
<option selected value="0">END TIME</option>
</select>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-12">
<textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Description..." data-type="description" name="description"></textarea>
</div>
<input type="hidden" name="tutorId" value="5" />
<div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary skl-green-button" value="BOOK SESSION" />
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: can cache the form html in a javascript variable and pass variable to popover content

Comment: that's how I'm doing it without Symfony2 forms, I'm asking how to handle it when I get a form generated from Symfony2, which takes a bit to load.

Comment: what difference does it make what the source of form is? Can use ajax and cache first time or load the form within main page.

Comment: it makes a difference, symfony2 generated form html includes csrf tokens. Even if I used ESI caching, the token would not change.